# Date formatting - making dd/m/yyyy into dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, date, format, vba

I got a pretty simple question (but yet I've been stuck at it for some time now). Does anyone know how to make the date value from dd/m/yyyy into dd/mm/yyyy in a variable?

```
dim lastdaylastmonth as date

lastdaylastmonth = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)
```

So this code, as of now, would return the last day of last month, so it will be 31/5/2015. For the sake of formatting, and a MID() down along the code to pull out the month string "05", I will need to convert the date to dd/mm/yyyy or 31/05/2015. Does anyone know the simple solution for this? I've tried:

```
lastdaylastmonth = format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

and  it still returns the same value! Any heroes out there? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **String**

```
Sub dural()
    Dim lastdaylastmonth As String
    lastdaylastmonth = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    MsgBox lastdaylastmonth
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: ++ Yup it was just a small change :) `Format` returns a string

Comment: @SiddharthRout  and leaving it in a **String** variable helps to insure the variable will be "parse-able"

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
lastdaylastmonth = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)
?lastdaylastmonth
31.05.2015 
? format(lastdaylastmonth,"dd.mm.yyyy")
31.05.2015
? format(lastdaylastmonth,"mm")
05
```

The last output is a string, ready to be used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method simply due to the fact that I have to deal with many different Excel versions around the world. Using format with "mm/dd/yyyy" will only work in the US (or whereever English is the defined language). In other counries the below code will still work.

```
Dim lastdaylastmonth As Date

'Last day of last month
lastdaylastmonth = Date - Day(Date) - 1

'Formatting it US-style regardless of international Excel or Windows settings
Debug.Print Right("0" & Day(lastdaylastmonth), 2) & "/" & Right("0" & Month(lastdaylastmonth), 2) & "/" & Year(lastdaylastmonth)
```